# splitting a name using characters

Tags: vbscript

I have different file names that I want to split so ex
Contents.js
jQuery.10.1.js
Main.css

Can someone tell me how can I get the extension part from these files like js or css .i was using the split function and using the . charatcer but it does not work in jquery.10.1.js .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the right tool - .GetExtensionName() - for the job:

```
>> Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>> Dim aTests : aTests = Split("Contents.js jQuery.10.1.js Main.css")
>> Dim sFiNa
>> For Each sFiNa In aTests
>>     WScript.Echo sFina
>>     WScript.Echo oFS.GetExtensionName(sFiNa)
>> Next
>>
Contents.js
js
jQuery.10.1.js
js
Main.css
css
```